# Error establishing a database conection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

While trying install wordpress i recieve following error

[image]

[image]

I use wampserver i have changed wp-config.php file and now it looks like this:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');//i used 127.0.0.1 too but no matter
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

wp-db.php file:
1379 line:

```
mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
```

1409 line:

```
$this->dbh = mysqli_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
```

but still no result I do not know what to do can anyone help me?

Comment: Try with this `define('DB_PASSWORD', '');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using default configuration of xampp/wamp try with

`define('DB_PASSWORD', ''); // for localhost`

generally localhost db config:-

```
host = localhost
user = root
password = '' (blank)
```

Comment: glad it's helpful for you you can accept helpful answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Is `root` really the MySQL user you want to connect as? Is `root` its password?

It's usually not necessary and from a security standpoint potentially very dangerous to let web applications use your MySQL root user. Create a new user for your WordPress instance, give it its own database:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE wordpress;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO blog@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '3AmAbsKCsrKDw':
```

Then use that user

```php
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'blog');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '3AmAbsKCsrKDw');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

That should let you connect. Verify that you can connect with those login credentials before continuing to your WordPress setup. WAMP includes a phpMyAdmin interface as far as I know, so try those credentials there.

Answer (score 1):

Update your wp-config.php file like this

define your database name when you create on your localhost or server

> define('DB_NAME', 'Your database name');

Ex:- You create your database name like "wordpress" then put database name like

> define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

If you run your project in local always put root and when you upload database in your server you put your database user name when you create database

> define('DB_USER', 'root');

Put your password when you create database on server other wise you can put ''

> define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
>
> define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
>
> define('WP_DEBUG', true);